# Instantiating an object inside of a prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I write this code here:

```
void Start() {
    index = Random.Range (0, Obstacles.Length);
    ChosenPrefab = Obstacles[index];
    Instantiate(ChosenPrefab, transform.position + offset, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

which is attached to my gameobject that i want chosenprefab to spawn in so that when i destroy the gameobject it destroys chosen prefab

Comment: Unclear from code provided but as you dont keep a reference to the instantated object. Quite possibly

Comment: Try a Using statement

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: More specific to Unity: https://answers.unity.com/questions/534314/how-to-delete-instantiated-gameobject.html

Comment: May I ask you why? When using `Instantiate` it is loaded into the **scene** ... you can not place a **scene** object as a child of a prefab **asset** ....

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to spawn everything under one parent?

```
void Start() {
    index = Random.Range (0, Obstacles.Length);
    ChosenPrefab = Obstacles[index];
    var go = Instantiate(ChosenPrefab, transform.position + offset, Quaternion.identity);
    go.transform.SetParent(transform); 
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that when you setparent you can add it to  a gameobject that isnt in the scene on play.

Comment: No, that's not possible. You must have GameObject in runtime in order to set other GameObject under it.

Comment: @JimWafer I agree, what you ask is not possible, makes little sense on runtime. And FYI there is an overload of [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) directly taking the parameter `Transform parent    Parent that will be assigned to the new object.`